# ESP-12F module "correct" wiring for usage as modem?

Tags: uart, esp8266

I have wired the ESP-12F module as shown in the diagram below.
I can not get reply when sending "AT" at 115,200 Baud 8bit, 1bit stop, no parity.

1. Is this the correct wiring?
2. Is there a special start-up sequence that might prevent the module from working properly if not followed?

[image]

Comment: Suggestion? Yes, narrow down the problem. It could be like *anything* from your description.

Comment: @EugeneSh. OK, narrowed it down to two questions.

Comment: Does it have any FW in it? Anyway, here is a tutorial http://www.instructables.com/id/Getting-Started-with-the-ESP8266-ESP-12/

Comment: GPIO0 should not be tied to GND, because in that case the module will start up in boot mode. Leave it to float or pull it up to 3.3 V. The correct command `AT\r\n`, I do not know if you use this format.

Comment: @EugeneSh. On the manual for this specific module, they suggest that when it will power up a short message will be sent out by the module. I assume this means it has firmware.

Comment: I can recommend this [tool](https://esp8266.ru/esplorer/) to verify the module.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments...

GPIO0 should not be tied to GND, because in that case the module will start up in boot mode. Leave it to float or pull it up to 3.3 V. The correct command AT\r\n, I do not know if you use this format. – **Bence Kaulics**